# Why does Rust not recognize that a variable is a &str?

Tags: rust, traits

The below code compiles and runs fine:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn display(x: &str) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let s: &str = "hi there";
    display(s);
}
```

However, if you change the `display` function to be

```
fn display(x: &Display)
```

It gives the following error:

```
src/main.rs:9:13: 9:14 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str` [E0277]
src/main.rs:9     display(s);
```

By changing `display(s)` to `display(&s)` it works again.

What is going on here? Clearly the type is `&str`, but when `&Display` is the input argument it doesn't recognize that.

Note: `&34` also works as an argument just fine. Is this because `Display` is actually implemented for `&str` and not `str`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are requesting that `&str` should be coerced to `&Display` (a reference to trait object), which seems to make sense since the type `str` implements `Display`.

Yet as of Rust 1.9 (and no current plans of changing this), the conversion to a trait object is only possible for `&T` to `&Trait` if the type `T` is “`Sized`”.

The reason is the implementation. A trait object like `&Display` consists of two fields, one pointer to the data, and one pointer to the table of trait methods (vtable). This representation is only possible for values whose references are “thin” which are exactly the types `where T: Sized`. A `&str` is a “fat” reference, it has a pointer and a length, and so a `str` can not be a trait object's data.

---

> Why does display(&s) work though? I guess that is a referene to the "fat" reference?

Yes, exactly. A `&&str`, is a ”thin” reference that points to the variable with the `&str` value. So it can be converted to `&Display`.

Comment: Why does `display(&s)` work though? I guess that is a referene to the "fat" reference? Are there other types that are "fat" referenes, or is `&str` special somehow?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why `str` isn't just a struct with the data and the length, instead of `&str`? Then `&str` would no longer be a fat pointer and we wouldn't have this problem!

Comment: I looked up fat pointers and this was a pretty good reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/38tv6n/when_is_a_reference_not_a_pointer/ I'll keep investigating...

Comment: this was also a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949579/understanding-pointer-types-in-rust

Answer (score 5):

(Promoted my edits to the main answer)

When you write `fn display(x: &Display)`, the function takes a value that can be coerced into a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html) by dereferencing it. Also Rust function requires the value size of the parameter `x` to be known at the compile time.

When `&34` (`&u32` type) is dereferenced and coerced into trait object, it becomes `u32` and its size can be determined.

When `&str` is dereferenced, it becomes `str` and its size cannot be determined as the length of a string can be anything.

By adding `&` to `&str` (`&&str`), it is dereferenced back to `&str`, which is a pointer and its size can be determined. I believe this is why the compiler only accepts `display(&s)` in your code.

Comment: This.. its coersion happening. Perhaps promote your edit into the main answer?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I promoted my edit (with some extra modifications for clarity) into the main answer.

Comment: The book says "A trait is object-safe if both of these are true: 1) trait does not require that `Self: Sized`; 2) all of its methods are object-safe". 

However only reference to `Sized` value can be casted to trait object

Comment: I would add to this answer (from my reading after getting help from everyone) that `str` is really just a wrapper for `[u8]`, who's size cannot be known at compile time. Thus, the "fat" reference.

Answer (score 1):

> By changing display(s) to display(&s) it works again.

It all goes down to `&str: Display (+ Sized)` and `str: !Display` (this is just a notation)

- `display(s)` expects `s: &Display`, => `&str: &Display` which is false.
- `display(&s)` expects `&s: &Display` => `&(&str) : &Display` which is true as `&str: Display`

Comment: `Display` implemented for `str`, not for `&str`. http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/up/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs.html#1371-1375