# Casting &[u8] to u64 without extra memory allocation

Tags: rust

I have a `mmap`ped file from which I read (and write) `Message`s. I have a byte slice (`&[u8]`) of the mmap's contents. My current struct definition of a `Message` is:

```
struct Message<'a> {
    bytes: &'a [u8]
    id: &'a MessageId(u64),
    // ... some fields omitted ...
}
```

What I'd like is to map the byte slice to the message's fields, but I can't seem to get this right.

I've been looking into `mem::transmute` but I keep doing something wrong here:

```
error: transmute called with differently sized types: *const [u8] (128 bits) to u64 (64 bits) [E0512]
let offset: u64 = unsafe { mem::transmute(self.bytes) };
```

From my understanding transmute "reinterprets" the buffer as another type. How should I go about fixing this? How about mapping subsequent fields (as e.g. `u32`, `&'a str`, etc.)?

Comment: Note that it doesn't make any sense to (de)serialize a struct with a reference. There's no way to guarantee that the pointed-at value will be in the same location, or even that it exists!

Comment: Also, a `&[u8]` is a [*fat pointer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953048/155423), explaining why it's 128 bits and why it would be a Bad Idea to `transmute` it.