# What's the difference between assigning to a *mut T and a &mut T?

Tags: pointers, rust

This code:

```
let mut a2 = 99;
let b: *mut i32 = &mut a2;
*b = 11; // does not compile , even after unsafe {*b}
```

Generates the error:

```
error[E0133]: dereference of raw pointer requires unsafe function or block
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     *b = 11;
  |     ^^^^^^^ dereference of raw pointer
```

But this code works:

```
let mut a2 = 99
let b = &mut a2;
*b = 11;
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: What's wrong with `unsafe {}`? Maybe you put it in the wrong place? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=388da28b6bfac187a3c0ec12e1798246&version=stable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two?

One is a *raw pointer* (`*mut _`) and the other is a *reference* (`&mut _`). As the book says:

> the compiler guarantees that references will never be dangling

Additionally, a reference will never be `NULL`. It is always safe to dereference a reference. It is not always safe to dereference a raw pointer as the compiler cannot guarantee either of those. Thus, you need an `unsafe` block:

```
unsafe { *b = 11; }
```

See also:

- [Understanding Pointer Types in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31949579/155423)
- [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html)
- [Unsafe Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html)