# When to use Rc vs Box?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

I have the following code which uses both `Rc` and `Box`; what is the difference between those? Which one is better?

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(1);
    let a1 = &a;
    let a2 = &a;
    let b = Rc::new(1);
    let b1 = b.clone();
    let b2 = b.clone();

    println!("{} {}", a1, a2); //=> 1 1
    println!("{} {}", b1, b2); //=> 1 1
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f969bf51c9ff678d7f7267794bf0218f&version=stable)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/) provides shared ownership so by default its contents can't be mutated, while [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/) provides exclusive ownership and thus mutation is allowed:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut a = Box::new(1);
    let mut b = Rc::new(1);

    *a = 2; // works
    *b = 2; // doesn't
}
```

In addition `Rc` cannot be sent between threads, because it doesn't implement `Send`.

The bottom line is they are meant for different things: if you don't need shared access, use `Box`; otherwise, use `Rc` (or `Arc` for multi-threaded shared usage) and keep in mind you will be needing `Cell` or `RefCell` for internal mutability.

Answer (score 27):

Looking at the example given in the description, I think the real question here is "when to use `Rc` versus `&Box`" (note the ampersand).

Both `Rc` and `&Box` store the underlying data on the heap, neither can be sent across threads, and both allow immutable sharing (demonstrated by the aforementioned example). However, the biggest difference is that `Rc` gives you a shared (immutable) *owned* value while with `&Box` you get a shared (immutable) *reference*.

In the `Rc` case, the underlying data will be dropped (freed/deallocated) whenever the last owner (whether the original one or any cloned one) gets dropped – that's the idea of reference counting. In the `&Box` case, however, there is only one owner: any shared references to it will become invalid immediately after the owner gets out of scope.

Said differently, contrary to a `Rc::clone()`, binding a variable to a new `&Box` (`let a2 = &a;` in the example) will not make it live any longer than it would otherwise.

As a concrete example, the following is valid:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let rc_clone;
    {
        let rc = Rc::new(1);
        rc_clone = rc.clone();
        // rc gets out of scope here but as a "shared owner", rc_clone
        // keeps the underlying data alive.
    }
    println!("{}", rc_clone);  // Ok.
}
```

But this isn't:

```rust
fn main() {
    let b_ref;
    {
        let b = Box::new(1);
        b_ref = &b;
        // b gets out of scope here and since it is the only owner,
        // the underlying data gets dropped.
    }
    println!("{}", b_ref); // Compilation error: `b` does not live long enough.
}
```

Comment: You probably _don't_ want to use `&Box<T>` and use `&T` instead. Box implements `Deref<Target=T>` so you can just do `&*my_box` to get an `&T`.

Comment: My aim was only trying to share how things work, not what people should use, but you have a good point, don't use `&Box<T>`!