# How do I recursively follow a self-referential Rc?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with an optional self-reference:

```
struct Pathnode {
    pos: Pos,
    parent: Option<Rc<Pathnode>>,
}
```

I want to follow the `parent` reference until the first child before the root node (The root node has no parent). I tried the following code:

```
let mut head: Pathnode = node;
while head.parent.is_some() {
    head = *head.parent.unwrap();
}
```

But this fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
   --> file.rs on line 134:24
    |
139 |                 head = *head.parent.unwrap();
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I get a `Pathnode` from the `Rc`? Alternatively, what other data type could I use for `head`? It's OK if I only get an immutable reference or similar at the end.

Comment: This seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377231/when-to-use-rc-vs-box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use references instead of trying to move values around.  This should work:

```
let mut head: &Pathnode = &node;
while head.parent.is_some() {
    head = head.parent.as_ref().unwrap();
}
```

Your code calls `unwrap()` directly on `parent`, which consumes the `Option`.  It is not possible to move a field out of a struct.

A nice alternative is to use `while let`:

```
let mut head: &Pathnode = &node;
while let Some(ref parent) = head.parent  {
    head = parent;
}
```