# How to share heap-allocated trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I have a trait and a struct implementing that trait (a trait object). I'd like to allocate my trait objects on the heap and to have other structures refer to them.

## Box field

```
trait Material {}

struct Iron {}

impl Material for Iron {}

// It works, but takes ownership of boxes.
struct Sphere {
    radius: f64,
    material: Box<dyn Material>,
}
```

This code works but I can't have two spheres sharing the same `Material`, because the `Box` owns the material and a sphere owns its `Box` field.

## Reference field

My next attempt is to use a normal reference instead of a `Box`:

```
struct Sphere<'a> {
    radius: f64,
    material: &'a dyn Material,
}
```

This also works, but as far as I understand, my `Material`s will be allocated on the stack instead of the heap. What if the `Material` value is really big and I'd rather have it on the heap? This leads me to the next approach which does not compile:

## Reference to a Box

```
struct Sphere<'a> {
    radius: f64,
    material: &'a Box<dyn Material>,
}

fn main() {
    let m1 = &Box::new(Iron {});
    let s1 = Sphere {
        radius: 1.0,
        material: m1,
    };
    assert_eq!(s1.radius, 1.0);
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
16 |         material: m1,
   |                   ^^ expected trait Material, found struct `Iron`
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::boxed::Box<(dyn Material + 'static)>`
              found type `&std::boxed::Box<Iron>`
```

I am not quite sure where `'static` comes from in that type and it looks like it confuses the type checker. Otherwise `dyn Material` and `Iron` can be unified as far as I can understand.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=797c332c3e14d52c92f1f3094c30826f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `Rc` or `Arc`

When you need *shared ownership*, `Rc` or `Arc` is usually the first tool to reach for. These types implement sharing by reference counting, so cloning one is cheap (just copy a pointer and increment the refcount). Either works handily in this case:

```
struct Sphere {
    radius: f64,
    material: Rc<dyn Material>,
}

let m1 = Rc::new(Iron {});
let s1 = Sphere {
    radius: 1.0,
    material: m1,
};
```

`m1` is of the concrete type `Rc<Iron>`, but because it implements the [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) trait, it can be [automatically coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/3650362) in contexts that expect an `Rc<dyn Material>`. You can make multiple `Sphere`s refer to the same material by `clone`ing `m1`. ([Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc9bebf1cfe478f6fd889819fd5ee0ed))

The difference between `Rc` and `Arc` is that `Arc` is safe to use for sharing between multiple threads, but `Rc` is not. (Also see [When to use Rc vs Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377231/3650362))

### References

As for your reference example:

> This also works, but as far as I understand, my Materials will be allocated on the stack instead of the heap.

It's true that *lifetimes* are derived from the stack, but the reference itself does not need to point to something on the stack. For example, you can take a reference to the `T` in a `Box<T>` by dereferencing the `Box`:

```
struct Sphere<'a> {
    radius: f64,
    material: &'a dyn Material,
}

let m1 = Box::new(Iron {});
let s1 = Sphere {
    radius: 1.0,
    material: &*m1, // dereference the `Box` and get a reference to the inside
};
let s2 = Sphere {
    radius: 2.0,
    material: &*m1,
};
```

This is even cheaper than using `Rc` because `&` references are `Copy`able, but even though the `Iron` itself is stored on the heap, the references that point to it are still bound to the lifetime of the *stack* variable `m1`. If you can't make `m1` live long enough, you'll probably want to use `Rc` instead of plain references.

### Reference to a `Box`

This approach should also work, although it is unnecessary. The reason it doesn't is because, although you can coerce a `Box<Iron>` to a `Box<dyn Material>`, you *can't* coerce a `&Box<Iron>` to a `&Box<dyn Material>`; the types are incompatible. Instead, you need to create a stack variable of type `Box<dyn Material>` so that you can take references to it.

```
let m1: Box<dyn Material> = Box::new(Iron {}); // coercion happens here
let s1 = Sphere {
    radius: 1.0,
    material: &m1,  // so that this reference is the right type
};
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I think for my current purposes dereferencing of the boxes should work fine. But it's nice to understand when to use Rc and Arc. The only thing I still don't understand is why my code with the reference to a Box doesn't compile...

Comment: @dying_sphynx I added some explanation. I think there is another question that goes into more detail on why `&T` -> `&dyn Trait` is a valid coercion but `&Box<T>` -> `&Box<dyn Trait>` isn't; if I can find it I will link to it.

Comment: One more interesting thing: I tried to inline calls to `Rc::clone` in your full example, but it didn't work (failed with the same problem of coercion of references you mention at the end). But when I used `m1.clone()` instead of `Rc::clone(&m1)` - it worked. That is unexpected, since I thought that `Rc::clone(&x)` and `x.clone()` should work the same: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51f4e673374091fa2409534bbc4478be)

Comment: @dying_sphynx I think that's because of the difference between [method auto-deref and coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion) (in this case unsized coercion, not deref coercion). `m1.clone()` will always resolve to the type of `m1`, which is `Rc<Iron>`. But `Rc::clone(&m1)` needs to infer the argument of `Rc<_>`, and it doesn't know that the coercion needs to happen "outside" the function call, so it picks the wrong thing (`Rc<dyn Material>` instead of `Rc<Iron>`).

Comment: [Here's two other ways I found to resolve it.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5ac143ae7ae9a43c94d32dd8f35434e)

Comment: I've tried your suggestions with references: `&*m1` works beautifully by creating a reference to the Box content, but it looks like just using `&m1` in this context doesn't work: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dab48d496bb4306deaea773a937ed76f)

Comment: @dying_sphynx You're right, thanks for the correction! I thought I had tried it but I must have made a mistake.