# Do I need an Rc type for storing a pointer to a Rust struct inside of it's member C struct

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I would like to store the pointer to a rust `struct` inside of it's member C struct. Is it required that the struct be enclosed in a `Rc` rather than a `Box`?
The reason I'm asking is because although there is shared ownership here, the pointer is only ever accessed from within `unsafe` member functions of the Rust struct and the C struct's lifetime is tied to that of the enclosing Rust struct.

Here's an example ->

```c
// C struct with constructor/destructor
struct c_foo {
    void*   internal; // pointer to rust `struct`
    /* ... */
};

struct c_foo* c_foo_new();
void c_foo_free(struct c_foo* foo);
```

```
// FFI struct generated by bindgen
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub internal: *mut libc::c_void, // pointer to rust `struct`
    /* ... */
}
```

```
// Rust struct that wraps the FFI struct
struct Bar {
    ptr: *mut Foo, // private
    /* ... */
}

impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Box<Bar> {
        unsafe {
            let mut bar = Box::new(Bar { ptr: c_foo_new() });
            let bar_ptr: *mut ffi::c_void = &mut bar as *mut _ as *mut ffi::c_void;
            (*bar.ptr).internal = bar_ptr;
            bar
        }
    }
}


impl Drop for Bar {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            c_foo_free((*bar.ptr).internal);
        }
    }
}
```

So there's a C struct `c_foo` with a `void *` that stores a reference to the Rust struct `Bar`. `Foo` is just the bindgen generated Rust wrapper for `c_foo`.
Do I need a `Box` or `Rc` in the `Bar::new()` function?

To clarify, there is no shared ownership on the Rust side. There is shared ownership b/w the Rust and C side so I guess there is no benefit in using a `Rc` type.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve with either `Box` or `Rc`. General guidance would be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377231/when-to-use-rc-vs-box), but why is it needed in the first place? You are already holding a pointer to a C struct. Does it have to be contained in another smart pointer? Moreover, the function `Bar::new` does not compile as it is.

Comment: I need it because the C library provides callbacks, and I need a pointer to the Rust struct in order to be able to call the Rust callback function. This question is basically a follow-up to my previous question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969071/how-to-properly-wrap-a-c-function-pointer-in-rust/60979574#60979574

Comment: OK, but that code does return a `Box<Bar>`, whereas this version of `Bar::new` returns just a `Bar`.

Comment: With that said, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377231/when-to-use-rc-vs-box) still applies on the Rust side: use `Rc` only if you need shared ownership in Rust code. Since C does not retain the semantics of this pointer type, C code needs to handle boundaries manually regardless.

Comment: I fixed the code, `Bar::new` should indeed return `Box<Bar>`. But I think what you said in your next comment makes a lot of sense. That is what I was getting at when I wrote in the question that '... although there is shared ownership...'. So I guess I might as well handle it manually and just use a Box type. Your comment `use Rc only if you need shared ownership in Rust code.` clears my confusion. Thanks!

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed if you now know the answer to your question, you can post it as an answer for others to find

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[E_net4 is renamed all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-is-renamed-all-the-time)'s comment answers my question -

> use Rc only if you need shared ownership in Rust code. Since C does not retain the semantics of this pointer type, C code needs to handle boundaries manually regardless.